# What does "Which of the many" mean?

Tags: meaning, possessive-of-which

What does "Which of the many" mean in the quote below?

> During the past 35 years, opinions on unemployment have significantly influenced our thoughts about the process of economic development in low-income countries, the economic strategies appropriate for governments committed to accelerating that process, and the best way for the rich nations to assist in that endeavor. **Which of the many** and sometimes conflicting opinions of economists regarding the magnitude, causes, and costs of unemployment in LDCs reigns as the conventional wisdom at any given time is not determined by purely scientific criteria.
>
> [Unemployment and Economic Development](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1153605)
> Albert Berry and R. H. Sabot,
> *Economic Development and Cultural Change*
> Vol. 33, No. 1 (Oct., 1984), pp. 99-116

Comment: It's "which of the" and then a list of possible options, followed by "is not determined ..."

Comment: Note for the future: the question title is used in the list of questions and needs to distinguish the *particular* thing you're asking about; quotes **must** be properly cited.

Comment: ı mean what kind of function "which of the many" has ? could you explain in shortly please ? is there any equivalent word to it ?

Comment: but is not the sentence supposed to be a question sentence ? instead it is affirmative ?

Comment: To get the grammar, strip out the excess baggage: "Which of the ... opinions ... reigns as the conventional wisdom ...is not determined by purely scientific criteria."  Those opinions are "many and sometimes conflicting." Just insert that phrase in the first ellipsis to see how it works.

Comment: The presence of "which" does not mean it's a question.

Answer (score 1):

The *which* clause here is not a question but a free relative clause, which plays the same syntactic role as a noun phrase:<sup>‡</sup>

> Which shirt do you want?  I haven't decided ***which shirt I want***.

What is involved here<sup>†</sup> is three different propositions which have been combined, modified and rearranged by various technical devices into a single sentence:

1. [<sub>A</sub> Economists have] [<sub>B</sub> many and sometimes conflicting opinions] [<sub>C</sub> regarding the magnitude, causes, and costs of unemployment in LDCs.
   ↓
   ↓ *rewrite the clause* Economists have opinions &c... *as the noun phrase* opinions ***of*** economists &c...
   ↓
   **NP:** *<sub>B</sub> the many and sometimes conflicting opinions <sub>A</sub> of economists <sub>C</sub> regarding the magnitude, causes, and costs of unemployment in LDCs*
2. [<sub>D</sub> At any given time] [<sub>E</sub>One of **NP**]  [<sub>F</sub> reigns as the conventional wisdom.]
   ↓
   ↓  *rearrange the clause*
   ↓
   **CL:** *<sub>E</sub> One of **NP** <sub>F</sub> reigns as the conventional wisdom [<sub>D</sub> at any given time*
   ↓
   ↓  replace *one* with the relativizer *which*
   ↓
3. Which of **NP** **CL**  is not determined by purely scientific criteria.

That is, the most popular opinion isn't necessarily the scientifically most probable one.

<sup>†</sup> That's another free relative clause, the subject of this sentence.
<sup>‡</sup> And that clause introduced by *which* is a **bound** relative clause: it modifies *propositions*.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence might have been written by a Demosthenes or Cicero for its complex multiplicity.  However, apart from the punctuation, the grammar is sound.

To understand it you need to strip out the core sentence, stripped of its host of qualifications.

> Which of the many and sometimes conflicting opinions of economists ... reigns as the conventional wisdom at any given time is not determined by purely scientific criteria.

Even simpler would be to turn it round to the easier order of subject active verb object.

> Purely scientific criteria do not determine which of the many and sometimes conflicting .. opinions of economists ... reigns as the conventional wisdom at any given time.

Into this the writer qualifies the noun opinions with a long chain of qualifiers, themselves modified.

The opinions are “many and sometimes conflicting.”.  More than that the opinions in question are those concerned with (“regarding”) “the magnitude, causes, and costs of unemployment in LDCs”.

So the direct answer to your question is that “which of the many” cannot be taken on its own.  “Many” is one of two adjectival phrases qualifying the noun “opinions”.  “Opinions is further modified by a long adverbial phrase explaining the topics of the opinions.

So why turn it round into the passive voice, making the reader wait all that length for the main point?

The writer is following a classical logic in which the sentence begins with the topic (the indirect question which opinion etc dominates at any time) and ends with the (logical) predicate - what s/he has to say about it - (that it is “not determined by purely scientific criteria”).

So it is certainly grammatical.  But is it clear?  Well to people like me who at school were translating the likes of Edmund Burke or Machiavelli into Latin or Greek prose, it is perfect.  It presents its argument in its logical order, and weaves into it the explanation of why there is conflict.  It is tight and compressed.

But perhaps the time for Ciceronian English has passed.